# Show a custom 404.html page if reverse proxy returns a http 404 error - Nginx 1.22.1

Tags: nginx, debian, reverse-proxy

So I have this nginx configuartion which is actually a reverse proxy to a MinIO (S3) app internally on http://localhost:9000

```
server {

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    client_max_body_size 500M;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Evreything works fine, but I want is that if the internal app returns 404 status then I want to show a custom 404.html page hosted at /var/www/html/404.html

I tried suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890920/4094231 but it just returns Nginx default error page.

[image]

---

I also tried

```
error_page 404 /var/www/html/404.html;
```

inside `location` and `server` block but it shows the 404 page of MinIO app.
[image]

---

```
nginx version: nginx/1.22.1

Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm
```